# Friendly URLs and Query Strings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting

In my project (ASP.NET Web Forms) I want to use [Friendly URLs](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls/), installed from NuGet.

I registered *route* in *global.asax* file:

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)  
    routes.MapPageRoute("Route", "default/{id}", "~/default.aspx?id={id}")
End Sub
```

With this code, I can use **default/123** instead of **default?id=123**. I want to add name, assigned to the id, in the url. So I can have url like this: default?123-Firstname-Lastnam. Name is saved in database, in single column. How can I add second parameter (name) to the url, add symbol `-` and display it without letters like this: `řčš` (because the application is in Chech language.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: You should read [Defining Routes for Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx).

Comment: I did. Wrote it exactly by the article, but when accessing route {value}, it is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To use FriendlyUrls**, after you install it from NuGet, go to your `global.asax` and enable it:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

    Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls()
    End Sub
    'rest of global
```

That is pretty much it. To get the values out of a URL for a page, you'll need to loop through the URL segments (don't forget `Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each segment As String In HttpRequestExtensions.GetFriendlyUrlSegments(Request)
        Dim val As String = segment
    Next
End Sub
```

So visiting `siteURL.com/default/123` will loop once and give you `123`, while `siteURL.com/default/122/Bilbo/Baggins` will loop three times and give you `122`, `Bilbo`, and `Baggins`.

**Or, if you just want to use plain routing** and not FriendlyUrls:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("id-route", "default/{id}", "~/default.aspx")
```

One good thing about routing is you can use the URL to pass variable data *without* using query strings. So the route to pass name data could look like

```
Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.MapPageRoute("name-route", "default/{id}/{firstName}/{lastName}", "~/default.aspx")
End Sub
```

And then default.aspx could be hit with `siteURL.com/default/123/Frodo/Baggins` and has:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim id As Integer = 0
    Int32.TryParse(Page.RouteData.Values("id"), id)
    Dim firstName As String = Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values("firstName"))
    Dim lastName As String = Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values("lastName"))
    'do something if id > 0
End Sub
```

**Other Considerations:** If you only want name in a single column, then you can combine the `firstName` and `lastName` variables for saving. Using `-` as a delimeter like you show in question isn't a good idea, as people can have hyphenated names. Saving name in a single column tends to cause problems as it makes it much harder to sort by first or last name, etc.

Also it appears you will be inserting into your database from a `GET` command. I would think this would be much more clear to do using `PUT` or `POST`.

Comment: I did exactly, what you wrote. But when I have url - site.com/default/123 and want to get the id, it is always 0. Shouldn't I add some references? I installed FriendlyUrls via NuGet.

Comment: @jstorm31 yes, sorry. That initial answer was just for general routing. I added an example of how to get URL segments from friendlyUrls.